# how to deep rename array keys if they don't match a regex pattern

Tags: php, arrays, regex, xml

I need to convert a JSON object to an XML document. I use [this class](https://github.com/easydigitaldownloads/Easy-Digital-Downloads/blob/master/includes/libraries/array2xml.php) that does the job quite well.

Problem is, sometimes my JSON object has attributes that throw an exception with the class, when element names are (W3C) illegal, like for this input:

```
{"first":"hello","second":{"item1":"beautiful","$item2":"world"}}
```

> Illegal character in tag name. tag: $item2 in node: second

The function that fires that is :

```
/*
 * Check if the tag name or attribute name contains illegal characters
 * Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn
 */
private static function isValidTagName($tag){
    $pattern = '/^[a-z_]+[a-z0-9\:\-\.\_]*[^:]*$/i';
    return preg_match($pattern, $tag, $matches) && $matches[0] == $tag;
}
```

What I would then like to do is to "clean" my JSON input before converting it to an XML.

I thus need to have a function that would reformat the input data BEFORE converting it to XML.

```
function clean_array_input($data){
    //recursively clean array keys so they are only allowed chars
}

$data = json_decode($json, true);
$data = clean_array_input($data);

$dom = WPSSTMAPI_Array2XML::createXML($data,'root','element');
$xml = $dom->saveXML($dom);
```

How could I do that ?  Thanks !

Comment: Not sure what you want, remove `$` in `"$xxx":"zzz"`? Try `preg_replace('~(")\$(\w+":")~', '$1$2', $text)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : question updated

Comment: I would recommend changing the class itself.  Changing the source data could cause problems when you have `{"item1":"beautiful","$item1":"world"}` as this would create two items with `item1` which in an array would overwrite and you would end up with just 1 value in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this. Create a new empty array, loop recursively through your data and filter keys. At the end return new array. To prevent duplicate keys we will use uniqid.

```
function clean_array_input($data){

    $cleanData = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = clean_array_input($value);
        }

        $key = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $key);
        if (isset($cleanData[$key])) {
            $key = $key.uniqid();
        }

        $cleanData[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $cleanData;
}
```